# How to launch a third-party app from their URL with an SMS on Android?

Tags: android

I've been thinking about using AWS's Simple Notification Service (SNS) to send texts. I'm making something that sends a text message to arm SimpliSafe when it thinks that I've left the house. I want to make the link so if someone clicks on it, it opens the SimpliSafe app. The only auto-links that apply are for web addresses and other things, though, so I can't use an `intent:///`. It looks like the URL `https://simplisafe.com/sn/..*` will launch an activity as in the following:

```
            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true">
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="simplisafe.com"
                    android:pathPattern="/sn/..*"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

I don't understand what this means, though. Is this regex? How do I trigger this? So far, if I make a sample request to `https://simplisafe.com/sn/..*`, or anything instead of the `..*`, with curl it gives me a `302 Moved Temporarily` error. If I make a sample request to `https://simplisafe.com/sn/index.html` with curl it gives me a `404 Not Found` error. If I open this URL from my browser, just like it would open from a text, it opens the Google Play store. How do I make it open the app instead of the Play Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when I launch it from the browser it doesn't do a lookup of the available apps first. The SimpliSafe page is designed to handle this, so it knows that the best option is to send me to the Play Store. If I had actually tested it with a text message, then I would have found out that it opens the SimpliSafe app.

Answer (score 0):

First, configure it in AndroidManifest.xml, add an intent-filter to the corresponding Activity, as follows:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="paraches" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
```

Next, add the relevant parsing code to the corresponding Activity, as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            if (uri != null) {
                String host = uri.getHost();
                String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                String id = uri.getQueryParameter("id");
                String path = uri.getPath();
                String path1 = uri.getEncodedPath();
                String queryString = uri.getQuery();
                Log.d("Alex", "host:"+host);
                Log.d("Alex", "dataString:" + dataString);
                Log.d("Alex", "id:" + id);
                Log.d("Alex", "path:" + path);
                Log.d("Alex", "path1:" + path1);
                Log.d("Alex", "queryString:" + queryString);
            }
        }
    }
```

Look at the Log, as follows:

```
host:schemedemo
dataString:paraches://schemedemo/get/info?id=10000
id:10000
path:/get/info
path1:/get/info
queryString:id=10000
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I might have forgotten to mention this, but I don't own SimpliSafe's app and I can't modify the manifest. Also, since I need to launch it from a text message, it needs to be a web link. But that might come in handy someday! Thanks!